# Equation numbering with chapter number in Word with atypical page layout

Tags: ms-word

My document is as follows:

```
                        Chapter 1
                   Title of the chapter

1.1 First subtitle

Blablabla

x + z = 1  (1.1)

Blablabla

y + z = 3 (1.2)

1.2 Second subtitle

Blablabla

x + y = 5 (1.3)
```

I want to number my equations with the following format: N.M where N is the number of the chapter and M: the number of the equation in Chapter N.

I know how to number equations with chapter number. The problem is that as my document is formated like above, the only one option I have is to number my equations as following:
N.P.M where N: chapter number, P: subtitle number and M: equation number. Why? Because, I do not know how to set my "Chapter 1" as a title but with the chapter number (here, 1) at the right like Chapter 1 instead of 1 Chapter.

Do you know how to get what I want? Someone to help?

Comment: This is not a Word programming question as it stands. If you went into caption numbering, chose include Chapter Numbering, and selected Heading 1 as the "Chapter starts with Style" option, should be enough. But as I say, it's not a programming problem.